# Slow Internet connection between India and USA

Tags: slow-connection

We have half our team in India and half in San Jose, CA. Two weeks in a row, on Sunday night the team in Noida, India (that is Dehli) cannot reach some sites in the USA.  For example they cannot reach commercial sites like LogMeIn or GoDaddy.  Traceroute shows slow connection but not impossible. And the connections are intermittent: sometimes they can connect for a while but then it disconnects very soon.

Does anyone know of any general internet problems between Asia and the USA right now?
Especially for internet traffic routed through Singapore and San Jose?

## Update:

From another contact, received this:
"This issue has been reported in NANOG mailing list as well. It is not only
India but the whole APAC has experienced high latency."
So I guess at this point it is not our provider but all of the Asia-Pacific region.

Answer (score 1):

Have you discussed this with your service provider(s)? That should be the first step in finding out about, and hopefully fixing, the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to do now is

1) Use traceroute or tracepath and find the router that is slow and its location etc. *This is for your own satisfaction.* :-)

2) Call the service provider and, if possible, threaten the poor call center executive. ;-) This, hopefully, should fix the problem.

Try [this](http://www.traceroute.org/) if you don't have experience in using traceroute.

Comment: We did a traceroute when the problem was first noticed.  Here is a partial list. But more to the point there are other reports now of general problems between Asia and the USA.  See the update to the original post.
<br />
8    91 ms    92 ms    89 ms  if-7-0-0.core1.S2E-Singapore.as6453.net [216.6.9
1.73]
<br />
  9   159 ms    93 ms   101 ms  Vlan1124.icore1.S9U-Singapore.as6453.net [116.0.
83.17]
<br />
 10   268 ms   266 ms   287 ms  Vlan1146.icore2.LAA-LosAngeles.as6453.net [116.0
.83.34]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything specific.  Could be router maintenance somewhere alone the line between the two.  That wouldn't be unheard of.

Where are the routers that show the slow access times when you are having the problems?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.internettrafficreport.com/asia.htm
or a speedtest to a server in San Jose

Maybe the TTL on your packets are expiring because of the hops involved?

Comment: Thanks for that link, Veejster!  It shows a sustained jump in packet loss since midnight last night. I'm feeling that is the cuase of the problems especialy on a VPN.